# Why SHAP values are the same every time, if kernel SHAP is based on random sample?

Tags: python, shap

I am learning SHAP, and have this quick question. If kernel SHAP values are estimated by randomly sampling feature values, why every time I received exactly the same SHAP values for the same model?

Any comments are very well appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would be interesting for all of us if you go through https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/shap/explainers/_kernel.py and tell us for sure that SHAP `KernelExplainer` is *deterministic* average over all possible coalitions over background dataset

Comment: @MichaelM Will you elaborate please on 10 feature threshold, perhaps with an answer and a link to the source code?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov: Done, thanks. And changed the 10 to 11 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of features p is not too large, then Kernel SHAP is deterministic. This can be seen by studying Scott Lundberg's [KernelExplainer code](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/shap/explainers/_kernel.py).

The `shap_values()` method of `KernelExplainer` has an argument `nsamples` with default "auto" set to 2^11 + 2p. Since Kernel SHAP requires at most 2^p - 2 different "on-off" vectors (and since Scott is very smart), your results will be exact for the selected background data up to p = 11 features.

In case p is > 11 (and you don't fiddle with the defaults), the impact of the random part is often negligible. Thus, even for larger p, the algorithm often looks as being deterministic.

Comment: @Micheal M Thank you very much for your answer! Just try to echo what you explained and make sure I fully understand. When the feature P is not too large, shap exhausts the possible combinations, and SHAP value could be considered as the exact SHAP value. Therefore, it is the same every time people runs it.

Comment: Almost. p is the *number* of features. And the Kernel SHAP values are *exact with respect to the selected background data*.

Comment: @Micheal M Assuming p=4, and so we have 14 "on-off" vectors. When we randomly sample from the background data (e.g., 5000 instances) according to these 14 vectors, the resulting dataset could be very different. Could you please elaborate on how the SHAP estimates remains the same and exact? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: No sampling from the background data is involved in the algorithm itself. Every on-off vector is combined with every row in the background  data. Then, the 14 * 5000 predictions are averaged into 14 values. This is not so well explained in the papers on Kernel SHAP.